# how to automatically map path to component

Tags: vue-router

Vue 2.5, vuex3, vue cli 3

I am trying to define the routes in vue, do i have to specify component for each path, let's say I have 50 components, then I have to define path for all these 50 component, e.g. path aaa - component aaa, path bbb - component bbb, path ccc - component ccc.? with all the path same as the component name, then I ended up having a long list of the route definition?

can I just define the route with some sort of wildcard, so it can try to automatically find the component based on the path, assuming the path name is same as component name? to make it simple, assuming I have only 1 level, all the 50 components are in component folder, with the name same as the path. how can I avoid to have to define for each route?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'd like to know if this is possible too.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically get a component via a component factory.

For example, this can be your `router.js` module:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import ViewFactory from '@/ViewFactory';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '**',  // wildcard route
      name: 'view-factory',
      component: ViewFactory
    }
  ]
});
```

And this is the ViewFactory:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="component" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Default from '@/components/Default';
import aaa from '@/components/aaa';
import bbb from '@/components/bbb';
import bbb from '@/components/ccc';

export default {

  components: {
    Default,
    aaa,
    bbb,
    ccc
  },

  computed: {
    component () {
      // Get last path part, equals component name
      let component = this.$route.path.split('/').slice(-1);

      // Fallback component
      if (Object.keys(this.$options.components).indexOf(component) === -1) {
        component = 'Default';
      }

      // Return component name
      return component;
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

When `this.$route.path` changes and you need to reload data, don't forget to watch the path and call a reload method after that in `ViewFactory`:

```js
watch: {
  // call again the method if the route changes
  '$route': 'load'
},
```

More information on this topic:

- https://flaviocopes.com/vue-dynamically-show-components/
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is